# reloadRowAtIndexPath didnt update height as expected IOS 8

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios8, autolayout

All, I m trying to create a collapse and expand effect for UILabel in a UITableView cell. The requirement is first display 2 lines of text and tap on a button to show the rest.

The first idea into my mind is to reset the **numberOfLines** property of the UILabel and then reload that row of TableView.

However, I encounter a strange behavior no matter I m using **reloadRowAtIndex** or **delete/Insert** which is shown below.

The following code, will result in that the first time I click on the button, it do call the setSelect:YES , but the button turns out to be still not selected, and row does the reload animation but will not have a correct height, only after I tap again, the button will have get selected and cell will get the correct height.

And in the collapse mode, I simply called "**reloadData**" for whole table, it works as expected, correct height, correct numberOfLines. I do wanna use **reloadAtIndexPath** method since it gives me the animation option. But I can t find out what I am doing wrong when using it, anyone can help ?

```
- (IBAction)actionTapOnExpandButton:(id)sender {

    NSIndexPath *path = sender.path // Get Path.

    UITableViewCell *cell = [_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:buttonCellIndexPath];

    if(!buttonTapped.selected){

        cell.videoDescriptionLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

        [_tableView beginUpdates];
        [_tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:buttonCellIndexPath, nil]  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [_tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:buttonCellIndexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [_tableView endUpdates];
        [buttonTapped setSelected:YES];
    }
    else {

        cell.videoDescriptionLabel.numberOfLines = 2;

        [_tableView reloadData];

        [buttonTapped setSelected:NO];
    }

}
```

Here I implemented the height method

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {  
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

in table init, I have

```
 _tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44;
```

Answer (score 1):

For your **'retarded selection problem'** of the button:

Just try toggling the `buttonTapped.selected` value **before** the `if` statement in your action method (`[buttonTapped setSelected: !buttonTapped.selected];` - and remove same method call from the `if` and `else` braces, of course). This might solve the button problem, as I suggest.

For the **'retarded cell height problem'**:

I would suggest to invalidate the label size **before** the `beginUpdates` call and **after** setting `numberOfLines` to `0`. just try `[cell.videoDescriptionLabel sizeToFit];`

Hope that will help.

Comment: Thanks for your help, the selection issue has been solved, however , the cell height is still not correct

I tried "SizeToFit", "SetNeedsLayout" on both cell and cell. xxLabel , still the first time click is not correct

Comment: Ok. Think I got the reason for that now: reloading or inserting a row causes the table view to ask its data source for a new cell for that row. So put the following code into `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method: `cell.videoDescriptionLabel.numberOfLines = buttonTapped.isSelected ? 0 : 1;` and the new/updated cell should have the right size. Of course, you need to hold a global reference to the `buttonTapped` in your controller. Please tell me if that helped and would be great if you marked the answer as correct (will update it accordingly to this comment if this is the right solution).